# in Django show String on UI when file is ready

Tags: python, html, django

I would like do next,

When press on submit button, Django generate some file (it takes some time, about a minute)
I would like that next to submit button will appear another button to download (locally) this file when generating was finished.

**screen shot:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7tUR.png)

**HTML:**

```
{% load bootstrap %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Create SWM Client Environment</title>  
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <h4 style="color: aliceblue;">Create SWM client environment</h4>
    </nav>
    <div style="padding: 20px;">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group container w-25">
                {{ form|bootstrap }}
            </div>

            <div class="container w-25">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Forms:**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    swm_server = forms.CharField(
        label='server',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Server IP or Server DNS'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        swm_server = cleaned_data.get('swm_server')
```

**Views:**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass  # does nothing, just trigger the validation

    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Where is your code?

Comment: Where's the code that generates the file? How are you running it asynchronously so that it doesn't block up the request? In general, what you want is not something we can answer simply and provide you the code with: you need to start an asynchronous task and you want to be able to check completion of the task. Search for django-celery for a package that does allow you to dispatch tasks. And search "ajax call to django" to make API calls using javascript to Django to check the status of the file.